# Get listbox SelectedItem string when using Display/Value Member

Tags: vb.net

I populated my listbox using display and value members. I know how to access the value of Id (e.g 134) but i would like somehow to take also item string which i can see on my listbox when i select it. How to access Display member value?

```
MyListBox.DisplayMember = "PicturePath"
MyListBox.ValueMember = "Id"
MyListBox.DataSource = GetElementPics.ListPicsByElementId
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GetItemText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext(v=vs.80).aspx) from the [`SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim picturePath As String = MyListBox.GetItemText(MyListBox.SelectedItem)
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext(v=vs.80).aspx):

> If the `DisplayMember` property is not specified, the value returned by
>   `GetItemText` is the value of the item's `ToString` method. Otherwise, the
>   method returns the string value of the member specified in the
>   `DisplayMember` property for the object specified in the item parameter.

If nothing is selected `GetItemText` returns an empty string. So if you want to handle that in a different way you should first check if  `SelectedIndex <> -1` or `SelectedItem IsNot Nothing`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the item by using `SelectedItem`...

For example:

```
 If ListBox1.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
   ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
 End If
```

Comment: your solution is not working when you bind as i did otherwise its ok